# Convert numerical string in lists where each list is in Pandas row to float

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, pandas, type-conversion

I have a column in `Pandas.DataFrame` where every row of this column is the list of numbers. But these number is typed as string

The column name is `allmz`, the dataframe is `exp_df`

```
print exp_df.iloc[:3]['allmz']
>2129    [445.120788574, 355.067465091, 355.069260997, ...
>2130    [445.120758057, 355.06748396, 355.069279865, 3...
>2131    [445.120880127, 355.067417985, 355.06921389, 3...
>Name: allmz, dtype: object
```

I tried to convert each number by `iteritems`but the type is still `str`. Although I assign `mzz = float(mzz)`.

```
for ind, mzlist in exp_df['allmz'].iteritems():
    for mzz in mzlist:
        mzz = float(mzz)
print type(exp_df.iloc[0]['allmz'][0])
><type 'str'>
```

Each list comes from `exp_df['allmz'] = exp_df['allmz'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" "))` so I tried to do

`exp_df[each] = exp_df[each].apply(lambda x: float(y) for y in x.split(" "))`

But I guess `lambda` is not applicable with `for` loop. How I can access and convert string in list in each row of `Pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: No, `mzz = float(mzz)` does _not do anything to the series_. It only changes the object that `mzz` references. Variables != Objects.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension inside apply i.e

**Setup**

```
m = pd.DataFrame(['1.2,2.3,3.4,4.5,6.5'],columns=['numbers'])
m['numbers'] = m['numbers'].str.split(',')
0    [1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 6.5]
Name: numbers, dtype: object
```

**Applying list comprehension**

```
m['numbers'] = m['numbers'].apply(lambda x : [float(i) for i in x])

type(m.loc[0,'numbers'][0])
float
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need add `[]` for list comprehension, `split(' ')` should be simplify by `split()` because default separator is whitespace:

```
exp_df[each] = exp_df[each].apply(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x.split()])
```

But much better is create columns if possible:

```
exp_df = exp_df.join(exp_df[each].str.split(expand=True).astype(float))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got one way but not so nice. I changed the list at `split` to `np.array` and after that changed to `float`

```
exp_df['allmz'].apply(lambda x: np.asarray(x.split(" ")).astype(float))
```

Still looking forward to a better structure one. I believe `for` loop should have a way somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Jan,

you can use simple list comprehension

`exp_df[each] = exp_df[each].apply(lamda array: [float(y) for y in array])`

You can have both string parsing and conversion done at the same time by using **numpy.fromstring** (it will return numpy array instead of list)

`exp_df['all_mz'].apply(lambda s: np.fromstring(s, sep = " "))`